# Laravel - NoSQL Unlimited Field Update

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am developing a custom CRM for a customer.

There needs to be an unlimited amount of fields. So I set up a base schema with all the fields and their names in MongoDB.

I’m trying to make it so when I patch the customer object in Laravel it goes through all the fields and updates them automatically. Here is what I have so far:

```
$customer = Customer::find($id);
$fields = CustomerField::all();
foreach($fields as $field){
          $fieldName = $field->name;
          $customer->$fieldName = $request->input($fieldName);
}
$customer->save();
```

Although this doesn’t seem to be working.

I don’t want to be using the fillable property because I need these fields to be flexible.

Comment: Have a look at the docs for the `guarded` property in which you can protect the fields you know the name. Maybe it can help you to simplify the code using `$customer->update($request->all());`.

Comment: Hey, this requires all these fields to be in the `fillable` property. I gave it a shot, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: It looks like my original code is working. I had duplicate field names which messed with the values going to the `$request`. Although it would still be nice if that code was more simplified.

Comment: You can use only `fillable` or `guarded`. If you have both declared on the model it might not work as expected. 
Thats what the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment) suggests.
I'm also assuming you're using a package like [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) to abstract the connection with MongoDB, if not, have a look at it.